# JAXB annotations for nested element lists

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have the following XML:

```
<mappings>
    <mapping>
        <parameter attr = "value">asdas</parameter>
        <parameter attr = "value2">d123asdsad</parameter>
        <parameter attr = "value3">0</parameter>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <parameter attr = "value">23123s</parameter>
        <parameter attr = "value2">qwerty</parameter>
        <!-- more parameter elements -->
    </mapping>
    <!-- more mapping elements -->
</mappings>
```

I have the following java classes to map it to:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "mappings")
public class Mappings { 
    @XmlElement(name = "mapping")
    private List<Mapping> mMappings;

    public List<Mapping> getMappings() {
        return mMappings;
    }

    public void setMappings(List<Mapping> aMappings) {
        this.mMappings = aMappings;
    }
}

public class Mapping {
    @XmlElement(name = "parameter")
    private List<Parameter> mParameters;

    public List<Parameter> getParameters() {
        return mParameters;
    }

    public void setParameters(List<Parameter> aParameters) {
        this.mParameters = aParameters;
    }
}

public class Parameter {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "attr")
    private String mName;

    @XmlValue
    private String mValue;

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String aName) {
        this.mName = aName;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return mValue;
    }

    public void setValue(String aValue) {
        this.mValue = aValue;
    }
}
```

When I try to unmarshall it with

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(BundleMappings.class);
Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
mappings = (BundleMappings)um.unmarshal(new File(myFile));
```

I get this error

```
If a class has @XmlElement property, it cannot have @XmlValue property.
```

I need parameter to have both the 'attr' attribute and content, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

By default [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementations consider public properties (get/set methods) and annotated fields as mapped (and separate).  The default mapping is `@XmlElement` so your properties will be considered as mapped this way.

**Solution #1**

Since you are annotating the fields you need to add `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)` on your classes.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Parameter {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "attr")
    private String mName;

    @XmlValue
    private String mValue;

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String aName) {
        this.mName = aName;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return mValue;
    }

    public void setValue(String aValue) {
        this.mValue = aValue;
    }
}
```

**Solution #2**

Annotate the get (or set) methods.

```
public class Parameter {
    private String mName;

     private String mValue;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "attr")
    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public void setName(String aName) {
        this.mName = aName;
    }

    @XmlValue
    public String getValue() {
        return mValue;
    }

    public void setValue(String aValue) {
        this.mValue = aValue;
    }
}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/jaxb-and-complex-types-with-simple.html

---

**UPDATE**

You will also need to use the `@XmlElement` annotation on the `mappings` property to specify the element name should be `mapping`.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "mappings")
public class Mappings { 
    private List<Mapping> mMappings;

    @XmlElement(name="mapping")
    public List<Mapping> getMappings() {
        return mMappings;
    }

    public void setMappings(List<Mapping> aMappings) {
        this.mMappings = aMappings;
    }
}
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Use `@XmlElement(name="mapping")` on your `getMappings()` method.