# How to translate Java list into XML using JAXB annotations?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

How can I translate Java list

```
List<String> locations
```

into XML representation

```
...

<locations>
    <location>/bob/app/l1.xml</location>
    <location>/bob/app/l2.xml</location>
    <location>/bob/app/l3.xml</location>
</locations>

...
```

and save JSON compatibility format at the same time:

```
...

"locations": ["/bob/app/l1.xml","/bob/app/l2.xml"]

...
```

I use Spring and my current XML format in which I get responses is

```
...
<locations>/bob/app/l1.xml</locations>
<locations>/bob/app/l2.xml</locations>
...
```

I use JAXB annotations

```
@XmlElement(name = "locations")
public void setLocations(List<String> locations) {
    this.locations = locations;
}
```

*UPD*

I've found a solution. I just need to use

```
@XmlElementWrapper(name = "locations")
@XmlElement(name = "location")
public List<String> getLocations() {
    return locations;
}
```

Comment: Is this internally in your application, or is it the response you want to get as XML/Json?

Comment: `<locations><location>a</location></locations>` I want to get.

Comment: Now I get `<locations>a</locations><locations>b</locations>`.

Comment: You can put a wrapper class around this method. Annotate the class with 'locations'. change this annotation to 'location'. hope that will yield you want u r looking for. Something similar can be found here 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202529/jaxb-annotations-for-nested-element-lists'

Answer (score 0):

as @renju said, you can wrap it like this..

```
@XmlRootElement(name="locations")
public class Locations {

    @XmlElement(name="location")
    private List<String> locations;

    //setter and getter
}
```

Comment: I got `"locations": {"location": ["A","B"]}`

Comment: and you want to end up with { "locations": ["A", "B"] } ?

Comment: Yes, I need it for JSON only.

Comment: try to annotate with @JsonProperty("locations")