# Serialize an object containing List field

Tags: java, web-services, serialization

I have a WebService that send a List of Vehicle to the Web Service Client, the Vehicle is implemented as follow :

```
public class Vehicle implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8169481181178317205L;
    private final String id;
    private final LocalDate depositDate;
    private final double price;

    private final ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<>();
    private final ArrayList<String> comments = new ArrayList<>();

    private Optional<Renter> renter = Optional.empty();
    private int rentalNumber = 0;
}
```

As you can see, the vehicle object contains 2 fields wich are ArrayList. When I want to create the Web Service I have multiple warning telling me that Vehicle (which is the only object I want to send over the network) and other object aren't respecting the JAX-RPC convention and may not get sent properly.

How to get rid of these warnings ? Is this an obligation ?

The first solution I implemented was to transform the list into an array but is there anything else ?

EDIT 5: The problem comes the fact to add a parameter in the method i want to use for the web service.I tried to add a method like this one :

```
public StatePayment lol(int lol){

    return StatePayment.DENIED;
}
```

And the Web Services Creation software returned me the same error. Isn't that possible to add a method with parameters ?

EDIT4:I created a fake method just to test what was the problem. It seems that when i had the parameter in the method signature i have the precedent error.

```
//Not working code
public StatePayment lol(Buyer buyer){

        return StatePayment.DENIED;
    }

//Working code
public StatePayment lol(Buyer buyer){

        return StatePayment.DENIED;
    }
```

I guess the problem comes from buyer but i can't get what could it be.

EDIT 3: When i want to create the webService by "new->WebService-> Selecting the methods.
I have the following error:

> IWAB0398E Error in generating WSDL from Java:  >java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error looking for paramter names in >bytecode: unexpected bytes in file

Is this a serialisation problem ?

The error happens when i select this method:

```
public int proceedToPayment(Buyer buyer) {

        //Calcul du prix total du shoppingCart
        long totalPrice = 0;
        for(Vehicle v : buyer.getShoppingCart()) {
            totalPrice += v.getPrice();
        }

        Bank buyerBank = buyer.getBank();

        //Convertir totalPrice en euros vers la monnaie du Buyer.

        if(buyerBank.bankTransaction(totalPrice, buyer) == StatePayment.DENIED) {
            return 0;
        }

        removeShoppingCartFromBDD(buyer.getShoppingCart());
        return 1;
    }
```

EDIT 2: To be more clear, my principal question is. Am i forced to get rid of all these warning messages knowing that the only object that i will send over the network are Vehicle and the ones that are inside Vehicle (Renter)

EDIT 1: The warning message

> The service class "MlvDataBaseImpl" does not comply to one or more
>   requirements of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification, and may not deploy or
>   function correctly.
>
> The method "exportObject" on the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl" is
>   overloaded. Overloaded methods are allowed by chapter 5.5.5 of the
>   JAX-RPC 1.1 specification, however, some JAX-RPC 1.1 compliant tools
>   may not allow overloaded methods or may generate WSDL with overloaded
>   operations as contrary to rule R2304 of the WS-I Basic Profile.
>
> The value type "MlvDataBase" used via the service class
>   "MlvDataBaseImpl" does not have a public default constructor. Chapter
>   5.4 of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification requires a value type to have a public default constructor, otherwise, a JAX-RPC 1.1 compliant Web
>   service engine may be unable to construct an instance of the value
>   type during deserialization.
>
> The value type "Renter" used via the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl"
>   does not have a public default constructor. Chapter 5.4 of the JAX-RPC
>   1.1 specification requires a value type to have a public default constructor, otherwise a JAX-RPC 1.1 compliant Web service engine may
>   be unable to construct an instance of the value type during
>   deserialization.
>
> The value type "Vehicle" used via the service class
>   "MlvDataBaseImpl" does not have a public default constructor. Chapter
>   5.4 of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification requires a value type to have a public default constructor, otherwise a JAX-RPC 1.1 compliant Web
>   service engine may be unable to construct an instance of the value
>   type during deserialization.
>
> The value type "Buyer" used via the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl"
>   does not have a public default constructor. Chapter 5.4 of the JAX-RPC
>   1.1 specification requires a value type to have a public default constructor, otherwise, a JAX-RPC 1.1 compliant Web service engine may
>   be unable to construct an instance of the value type during
>   deserialization.
>
> The method "registerVehicle" on the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl"
>   uses a data type, "java.time.LocalDate", that is not supported by the
>   JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or
>   deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web
>   service may result.
>
> The method "getRentableVehicles" on the service class
>   "MlvDataBaseImpl" uses a data type, "java.util.List", that is not
>   supported by the JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not
>   serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure
>   of the Web service may result.
>
> The method "clone" on the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl" uses a
>   data type, "java.lang.Object", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC
>   specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize
>   correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may
>   result.
>
> The method "exportObject" on the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl"
>   uses a data type, "java.rmi.server.RemoteStub", that is not supported
>   by the JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize
>   or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web
>   service may result.
>
> The method "exportObject" on the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl"
>   uses a data type, "java.rmi.Remote", that is not supported by the
>   JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or
>   deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web
>   service may result.
>
> The method "exportObject" on the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl"
>   uses a data type, "java.rmi.Remote", that is not supported by the
>   JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or
>   deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web
>   service may result.
>
> The method "exportObject" on the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl"
>   uses a data type, "java.rmi.Remote", that is not supported by the
>   JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or
>   deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web
>   service may result.
>
> The method "exportObject" on the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl"
>   uses a data type, "java.rmi.Remote", that is not supported by the
>   JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or
>   deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web
>   service may result.
>
> The method "exportObject" on the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl"
>   uses a data type, "java.rmi.Remote", that is not supported by the
>   JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or
>   deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web
>   service may result.
>
> The method "exportObject" on the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl"
>   uses a data type, "java.rmi.server.RMIClientSocketFactory", that is
>   not supported by the JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may
>   not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete
>   failure of the Web service may result.
>
> The method "exportObject" on the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl"
>   uses a data type, "java.rmi.server.RMIServerSocketFactory", that is
>   not supported by the JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may
>   not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete
>   failure of the Web service may result.
>
> The method "unexportObject" on the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl"
>   uses a data type, "java.rmi.Remote", that is not supported by the
>   JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or
>   deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web
>   service may result.
>
> The method "setLog" on the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl" uses a
>   data type, "java.io.OutputStream", that is not supported by the
>   JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or
>   deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web
>   service may result.
>
> The method "getLog" on the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl" uses a
>   data type, "java.io.PrintStream", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC
>   specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize
>   correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may
>   result.
>
> The method "getRef" on the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl" uses a
>   data type, "java.rmi.server.RemoteRef", that is not supported by the
>   JAX-RPC specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or
>   deserialize correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web
>   service may result.
>
> The method "toStub" on the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl" uses a
>   data type, "java.rmi.Remote", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC
>   specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize
>   correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may
>   result.
>
> The method "toStub" on the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl" uses a
>   data type, "java.rmi.Remote", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC
>   specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize
>   correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may
>   result.
>
> The method "equals" on the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl" uses a
>   data type, "java.lang.Object", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC
>   specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize
>   correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may
>   result.
>
> The service class "MlvDataBaseImpl" does not have a public default
>   constructor. Chapter 10.1 of the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification requires a
>   service class to have a public default constructor, otherwise a
>   JAX-RPC 1.1 compliant Web service engine may be unable to construct an
>   instance of the service class to handle an incoming request message.
>
> The field or property "declaringClass" on the value type
>   "java.lang.Enum" used via the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl" has a
>   data type, "java.lang.Class", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1
>   specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize
>   correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may
>   result.
>
> The field or property "depositDate" on the value type "Vehicle" used
>   via the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl" has a data type,
>   "java.time.LocalDate", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1
>   specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize
>   correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may
>   result.
>
> The field or property "comments" on the value type "Vehicle" used
>   via the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl" has a data type,
>   "java.util.List", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1
>   specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize
>   correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may
>   result.
>
> The field or property "scores" on the value type "Vehicle" used via
>   the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl" has a data type, "java.util.List",
>   that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1 specification. Instances of
>   the type may not serialize or deserialize correctly. Loss of data or
>   complete failure of the Web service may result.
>
> The field or property "declaringClass" on the value type
>   "java.lang.Enum" used via the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl" has a
>   data type, "java.lang.Class", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1
>   specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize
>   correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may
>   result.
>
> The field or property "shoppingCart" on the value type "Buyer" used
>   via the service class "MlvDataBaseImpl" has a data type,
>   "java.util.ArrayList", that is not supported by the JAX-RPC 1.1
>   specification. Instances of the type may not serialize or deserialize
>   correctly. Loss of data or complete failure of the Web service may
>   result.

Comment: Can you add warning message to your question?
Also you should change ArrayList to List:
private final List<Integer> comm = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: I uploaded the message.

Comment: The only warning in that huge list that refers to Vehicle seems to be the one comlaining about the lack of a public default constructor. So, how about adding a public default constructor?

Comment: @JB Nizet sa you said i had public default constructor but now i have the error IWAB0398E Error in generating WSDL from Java:  java.lang.IllegalStateException" on a specifiq method and i can't create the WebService because of it. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this post [JAXB annotations for nested element lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202529/jaxb-annotations-for-nested-element-lists) for more details, how to serialize lists.

As for the warnings, you need to search for each one in SO, there are many different subjects involved.