# Marshalling multiple object entries into a file, using an XML file and generated JAXB helper classes

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

And the generated JAXB helper class:

```
package itemOrder;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "title",
    "author",
    "publisher",
    "description",
    "price",
    "publicationYear"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "book")
public class Book {

@XmlElement(name = "Title", required = true)
protected String title;
@XmlElement(name = "Author", required = true)
protected String author;
@XmlElement(name = "Publisher", required = true)
protected String publisher;
@XmlElement(name = "Description", required = true)
protected String description;
@XmlElement(name = "Price")
protected float price;
@XmlElement(name = "PublicationYear")
protected int publicationYear;
@XmlAttribute(name = "ISBN")
protected Integer isbn;

/**
 * Gets the value of the title property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the title property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public void setTitle(String value) {
    this.title = value;
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the author property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the author property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public void setAuthor(String value) {
    this.author = value;
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the publisher property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public String getPublisher() {
    return publisher;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the publisher property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public void setPublisher(String value) {
    this.publisher = value;
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the description property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the description property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link String }
 *     
 */
public void setDescription(String value) {
    this.description = value;
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the price property.
 * 
 */
public float getPrice() {
    return price;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the price property.
 * 
 */
public void setPrice(float value) {
    this.price = value;
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the publicationYear property.
 * 
 */
public int getPublicationYear() {
    return publicationYear;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the publicationYear property.
 * 
 */
public void setPublicationYear(int value) {
    this.publicationYear = value;
}

/**
 * Gets the value of the isbn property.
 * 
 * @return
 *     possible object is
 *     {@link Integer }
 *     
 */
public Integer getISBN() {
    return isbn;
}

/**
 * Sets the value of the isbn property.
 * 
 * @param value
 *     allowed object is
 *     {@link Integer }
 *     
 */
public void setISBN(Integer value) {
    this.isbn = value;
}
```

}

And in the Main, using the XML template, I am setting data for the defined elements:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    itemOrder.Book quickXML = new itemOrder.Book();

    quickXML.setAuthor("Lev Tolstoi");
    quickXML.setDescription("Russion fixction about 1st world war");
    quickXML.setISBN(62129985);
    quickXML.setPrice((float)12.6);
    quickXML.setPublisher("Progress");
    quickXML.setTitle("War and Peace");
    try {            
        javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext jaxbCtx = javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(quickXML.getClass().getPackage().getName());
        javax.xml.bind.Marshaller marshaller = jaxbCtx.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "UTF-8"); //NOI18N
        marshaller.setProperty(javax.xml.bind.Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("xmlFile.xml");
        marshaller.marshal(quickXML, os);
    } catch (javax.xml.bind.JAXBException ex) {
        // XXXTODO Handle exception
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("global").log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex); //NOI18N
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

and then marshalling them into a file. The question is, how can I marshal multiple entries of the data into ONE file. So for example: I would like to marshal this:

```
quickXML.setAuthor("Lev Tolstoi");
quickXML.setDescription("Russion fixction about 1st world war");
quickXML.setISBN(62129985);
quickXML.setPrice((float)12.6);
quickXML.setPublisher("Progress");
quickXML.setTitle("War and Peace");
```

and this:

```
quickXML.setAuthor("Robert Schwentke");
quickXML.setDescription("description description description");
quickXML.setISBN(62129432);
quickXML.setPrice((float)10.9);
quickXML.setPublisher("Regress");
quickXML.setTitle("Red");
```

at the same time, into the same file. Any ideas?

Comment: so this doesn't answer your question. but. i'm wondering. is there any reason why you're not making use of import statements? for example. at the top of your main class you could import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller; and in the method itself just type Marshaller marshaller = jaxbCtx.createMarshaller(); ... Are you making use of an IDE? IDEs do a good job of sorting this stuff out for you. you shouldn't be using fully qualified class names in your code. it makes the lines a mile long & your code much harder to read.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAXB annotations for nested element lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202529/jaxb-annotations-for-nested-element-lists)

Comment: You can make a wrapper class and put your books in a book list:
See here:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202529/jaxb-annotations-for-nested-element-lists)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap 'book' elements with a 'books' tag

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/books"
    xmlns:tns="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/books"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:element name="books">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="book">
                    <xsd:element name="Title" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Author" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Publisher" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Description" type="xsd:string"/>
                    <xsd:element name="Price" type="xsd:float"/>
                    <xsd:element name="PublicationYear" type="xsd:int"/>
                <xsd:element name="book">
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="ISBN" type="xsd:int"/>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```